# What's the most Pythonic way of determining endianness?

Tags: python, endianness

I'm trying to find the best way of working out whether the machine my code is running on is big-endian or little-endian. I have a solution that works (although I haven't tested it on a big-endian machine) but it seems a bit clunky:

```
import struct
little_endian = (struct.pack('@h', 1) == struct.pack('<h', 1))
```

This is just comparing a 'native' two-byte pack to a little-endian pack. Is there a prettier way?

Comment: Why do you need to know? Your solution seems good enough, but you certainly don't have to know when using 'struct' itself?

Comment: True, but I'm not using the struct module (perhaps I should be, but I'm not the original author of the code I'm fixing).

Answer (score 117, accepted):

The answer is in the [sys module](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html):

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.byteorder
'little'
```

Of course depending on your machine it may return `'big'`. Your method should certainly work too though.