# How to get endianness of numpy dtype

Tags: python, numpy, endianness

Related to [Determine the endianness of a numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34097845/2988730)

Given an array

```
x = np.arange(3)
```

I can get the byte order by doing

```
>>> x.dtype.byteorder
'='
```

How do I find out if this is big or little endian? I would like to get `'<'`, `'>'` or `'|'` as the output, not `'='`.

To be clear, I am not hung up on what format the information comes in. I just want to know "big endian", "little endian" or "irrelevant", but I don't care if it's "native" or not.

Comment: I might be missing your question here, but just check the native byteorder with `sys.byteorder`?

Comment: Maybe this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/1346039/4909087

Comment: @miradulo. I think you are understanding perfectly. I am very surprised that there is no way to get that from numpy directly, given that numpy has to access that information at some point, presumably.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Probably just check [`sys.byteorder`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.byteorder). Even the [`numpy.dtype.byteorder` examples](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dtype.byteorder.html#numpy.dtype.byteorder) in the docs use `sys.byteorder` to determine what's native.

```
endianness_map = {
    '>': 'big',
    '<': 'little',
    '=': sys.byteorder,
    '|': 'not applicable',
}
```

Comment: In that case, I don't have much choice unfortunately.

Comment: I was thinking of something more like `nativecode = '>' if sys.byteorder == 'big' else '<'; x.dtype.byteorder.replace('=', nativecode)`

Answer (score 2):

You can swap the endianness twice to make numpy reveal the true endianness:

```
dtype_nonnative = dtype.newbyteorder('S').newbyteorder('S')
dtype_nonnative.byteorder
```

Comment: I think I understand why that happens under the hood, but seriously, whyyyyyyyyy?

Comment: How about a PR to add a property to `dtype` to always get `<`, `>` or `|`?

Comment: That's a surprise, considering that even explicitly constructing `dtype('<i4')` will produce a `byteorder` of `'='` if native is little-endian. I would consider this a bug.

Comment: @user2357112 A bug in which direction? Explicitly constructed dtypes should product explicit byteorders, or `newbyteorder` should toggle between `=` and one of `{<, >}`?

Comment: @miradulo: I'd expect `newbyteorder` to produce `'='` when the resulting byte order is the same as the native byte order. (The fact that explicit `dtype('<i4')` produces `'='` when native is little-endian is documented, while the `newbyteorder` behavior isn't.)

Comment: @user2357112 Seems sensible, I didn't notice the comment in the docs there. Thanks!

Comment: Another fun fact: `x.newbyteorder().newbyteorder()` does not do the same thing, where `x` is the array, but it does when it is the `dtype`.