# Read a file and write the file's binary to a text document

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, binaryfiles

I am using Python 3.10 and I am trying to read a Windows executable file, and output the binary data in a text format (1's and 0's) into a text file. I only require the binary, I do not want the offsets and the ASCII representation of the bytes. I do not want any spaces or new lines.

```py
total = ""
with open("input.exe", "rb") as f:
    while (byte := f.read(1)):
        total = total + byte.decode("utf-8")
with open("output.txt", "w") as o:
    o.write(total)
```

However, it is not working, I am presented with the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "converter.py", line 4, in <module>
        total = total + byte.decode("utf-8")
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x90 in position 0: invalid start byte
```

Comment: That's because it's not possible to convert all binary bytes to ASCII.

Comment: Given, for example, the binary `A\0` (letter A + NUL character), what would you expect in your text file?

Comment: I do not want to convert it into ASCII. I want my HelloWorld.exe program converts into a text file which shows its binary representation.

Comment: (ASCII was a typo -- sorry. Meant utf8.) Are you thinking like a hexdump, like `od`?

Comment: I want my output.txt file to contain 1010010101101000011101010101010101000111110101 as an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code should do what you want:

```py
with open("input.exe", "rb") as f:
    buf = f.read()

with open("output.txt", "w") as o:
    binary = bin(int.from_bytes(buf, byteorder='big'))[2:] # or byteorder='little' as necessary
    o.write(binary)
```

Beware that it might hog up memory when dealing with very large files.

Comment: Perfect, thank you so very much! What is the byte order?

Comment: Basically the way memory is stored...you can read about it. I'm not sure what is correct, but I always do `big`. https://stackoverflow.com/a/1346039

Comment: On Windows it's little endian.